# Watchkit Problems with presentControllerWithName in Swift

Tags: swift, watchkit

My Problem:
I created an AppleWatch APP with an Tableview.
By tapping on special Rows i want to switch to an DetailController

So in my didSelectRowAtIndex Methode i use a switch-case function to find the row i want to show a Detail

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {    
    switch(status) {
    case "on":
        Println()
    case "off":
        Println()
    case "value":
        self.presentControllerWithName("MyValue", context: "TheValue")
}
```

In my DetailViewController i just want to show the Value in an Label.
so i did this:

```
@IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
       var TheValue = context as? String
    label.setText(TheValue)
    // Configure interface objects here.
}
```

Now is the behaviour: Without the Outlet the DetailViewController is shown, but with the Outlet just the Activity Indikator runs and nothing happens!

Where is my mistake??

Comment: The outlet may have an invalid connection, try to delete the connection in InterfaceBuilder and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested all Tipps but nothing works as i want to!

Now i found the solution! The Trick is to deselect the 'Hides When Loading' Option of the new Interface Controller. Then it works perfect!

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all: don´t do it like that. Wire up the segues from a Table Row to the next Controller via Storyboard instead of pushing or presenting it in code. Then you only have to set the context for the next Controller like this:

```
override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    if models.count > rowIndex {
        return models[rowIndex]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Second: did you wire up the label outlet correctly to your storyboard? Show some more of your code and screenshots of your storyboard. Or, even better, upload you project to github and show it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with presenting controllers from code, its perfectly legal. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: It´s legal, right, but it may not be best practice. Depends on the usage of the 'to-be-opened-ViewController'. If the new Controller is only opened from one source point, it´s better to do the segue in Storyboard. That way you can perfectly see the connection of Controllers in your Storyboard. Otherwise, you only end up having many Controllers lying around unconnected that are 'magically' opened somewhere in code. Don´t get me wrong, I´m not much of a Storyboard guy, but if I have to use it, I also want to use the advantages.

Comment: ok i'll use the segue in Storyboard, but how can i make a difference between 1.) use the segue and change to a new ViewController and 2.) don't change to another Controller and do something other??

Comment: By using a different Table Row instance. Every Table Row in your WKTableView can do a different segue. You specify the number of different Table Rows available in your Storyboard (Attributes Inspector > Table > Rows).